# Accept any certificate for SSL

Tags: c#, ssl

I have small TcpClient app to connect to a server using SSL (SSlStream class)

My question is, how to accept any ssl certification when connecting?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static bool RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, 
    X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors) 
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: No problem. Please note it isn't a good idea to do this if you need to trust the remote server. For example, if you were sending something confidential to it.

Comment: Sure, agreed. I just need it on a testing environment.